# IntelliJ IDEA 12 with Play 2.0. No Java/Scaladocs

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I configured IntelliJ IDEA 12 to work with Play 2.0 framework: installed `Scala`, `Play 2.0` plugins and downloaded `play 2.0.4` framework (I choosed `play 2.0.4` root directory when created new project from IDEA).

All works fine, i.e. I can run code and see result in browser,  but I miss ScalaDocs/JavaDocs in IDE (when pressing `Ctrl+Q`) for both `Play 2.0` and `Scala`. How I can configure it?

Comment: Does `Ctrl`+`Q` (shows documentation of whatever your cursor is on) not work? Or is it some other feature you mean?

Comment: @ghik yes, `Ctrl+Q` not work. Edited post, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to run with the `with-sources` option.

Easiest if you enter the play console mode.

```
play
```

Then run the `with-sources` option together with the idea command

```
idea with-sources=yes
```

Comment: thanks, but I encountered  2 problems:  
1. Your suggestion works only if I create project _using IDEA_ and then in command line run `play`, `idea with-sources`. I.e. if I create project using `play new project` and then run `idea with-sources` then IDEA can't recognize templates name (e.g. `index` and `main` 'standard' templates) and highlights its with red color.
2. I still don't see `ScalaDoc`. I tried to download `scaladoc` separately and setting it as `JavaDoc` to `scala-library` dependency (in `Project Structure`), but no effect..

Comment: I'm getting a lot of warnings like:
    [info] Trying to create an Idea module lunch-orders
    [warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0!scala-library.jar(doc) (0ms)
    [warn] ==== local: triedd
    [warn]   /home/delor/play-2.1.1/repository/local/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0/docs/scala-library-javadoc.jar